# Tag proposals #1

Tags: discussion, tags

Some of these I agree with, some I disagree with, but they came up in chat recently, so I am putting them here:

1. Change [teaching-analogy](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching-analogy) to [examples](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/examples), in line with [matheducators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/examples)
2. Merge [code-style](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-style) and [coding-conventions](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-conventions) into [coding-style](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-style)
3. Change [group-assignment](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-assignment) to [group-work](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-work)
4. (Larger change) Go on a giant purge of [meta tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) throughout the site, which would eliminate many of the above named tags above entirely.

Comment: [Please do not make such broad threads about tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278104/are-general-tag-discussion-threads-ever-useful). Make one thread per tag or per group of closely-related tags.

Comment: I know you created subsequent threads for individual points in this - maybe you could add links?

Comment: Thanks for the last close vote! :) Personally, I'd prefer that this thread simply die, though I suppose I can put links in once I get home.

Answer (score 1):

1. Maybe just [lesson-design](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lesson-design). Any example or analogy takes place within the context of a lesson. That would pair nicely with [curriculum-design](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curriculum-design). One for micro issues and one for macro. Plus, [teaching-analogy](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching-analogy) is ambiguous by itself. Is teaching the analogy? Is something an analogy for teaching? For teaching *with*?
2. I like the focus simply on [style](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style), whether it be preceded by code, coding, or programming.
3. Yes.
4. Absolutely, beginning, in my mind, with [introductory-programming](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/introductory-programming). Reading through questions with it, I didn't see *any* that were made better or were categorized more clearly because of it. I had one in particular (Raspberry Pi course development) that used it, and looking back, I can see that it added nothing other than useless metadata. I got to the point and summarized it well with [raspberry-pi](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raspberry-pi) and [curriculum-design](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curriculum-design). Plus, introduction to what? To whom? At what level? The tag almost by definition wants for more information. As a result it does less good than harm.

Comment: "Introduction ... at what level?" How else would you clasify level if not introductory/beginner, intermediate, advanced?

Comment: @thesecretmaster Why even classify level? That's the point I'm trying to illustrate. It doesn't add to the accuracy of the categorization, and it is incredibly subjective.

Comment: As a teacher, covering introductory topics is different from covering advanced topics.

Comment: @thesecretmaster Potentially, but sound pedagogy remains sound regardless of the level or topic. And if the question is about an intro or an advanced topic, the topic should be the tag

Comment: Into algorithms != advanced algorithms. Unless you want 3 tags per topic, the current approch is more effective.

Comment: @thesecretmaster But in that instance, let's say you have beginners learning bubble sort and advanced students learning Dijkstra's algorithm. For the former, [tag:bubble-sort] and [tag:sorting-algorithm] sum up everything. With the latter, use [tag:dijkstra], [tag:graph-theory], and [tag:searching-algorithm]. If someone said they had an intro level question, we'd ask for much more context. The same goes for tags. Intro has to be supplemented by more specific categories. As a result it cannot stand alone. If it cannot stand alone, as Atwood's meta-tag post argues, it's not a worthwhile tag.

Answer (score 0):

1. This seems like a broadening rather than a narrowing. [examples](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/examples) would encompass any way of demonstrating something, while [teaching-analogy](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching-analogy) only refers to analogies and historically has been a fairly narrow tag.
2. This makes perfect sense. Code style is the same idea as conventions. The only slight tweak I'd make it simply merging [code-style](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-style) into [coding-conventions](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-conventions) because it's simply much more used. Either way, I'd wait on a giant retag because mods can do that without bumping them.
3. Sure, I do like this phrasing better, and it is slightly broader. I don't really see a huge difference, but it is a small improvement.
4. This needs to be more specific, and maybe should be a separate question. All the above tags seem valuable to me, but I'd elaborate on a later meta question.